# youtube-dl output errors, win10

Tags: windows-10, youtube-dl

Can someone tell me what is wrong here? The download appears to be successful but the file is nowhere to be found.

```
C:\Users\lmaxi\OneDrive\Desktop\YouTube-DL>youtube-dl -v 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjaayCARwro 
[debug] System config: [] 
[debug] User config: ['--get-filename', '-x', '--audio- 
format', 'flac', '--output', 'C:/Users/lmaxi/Downloads/% 
(title)s-%(ext)s.%(ext)s'] 
[debug] Custom config: [] 
[debug] Command-line args: ['-v', 
'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mjaayCARwro'] 
[debug] Encodings: locale cp1252, fs mbcs, out cp850, pref 
cp1252 [debug] youtube-dl version 2018.10.05 
[debug] Python version 3.4.4 (CPython) - Windows-10-10.0.17134 
[debug] exe versions: avconv 11.3, avprobe 11.3 
[debug] Proxy map: {} C:\Users\lmaxi\Downloads\Kodak Black - 
ZEZE (feat. Travis Scott & Offset) [Official Audio]-webm.webm
```

Comment: Isn't it C:\Users\lmaxi\Downloads\Kodak Black - 
ZEZE (feat. Travis Scott & Offset) [Official Audio]-webm.webm` ???

Comment: Nope. It won't recognize the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. 
The '--get-filename' option conflicts with '--output' or '-o' output option. 
Nothing like a good nights sleep to get a fresh perspective.